# Draw the table like 6³ = 3³ + 4³ + 5³ to 100³ = 35³ + 70³ + 85³

Tags: php, algorithm, performance, mathematics

I want to draw the table like this:

> ```
> 6³ = 3³ + 4³ + 5³
> 9³ = 1³ + 6³ + 8³
> 12³ = 6³ + 8³ + 10³
> 18³ = 2³ + 12³ + 16³
> 18³ = 9³ + 12³ + 15³
> 19³ = 3³ + 10³ + 18³
> 20³ = 7³ + 14³ + 17³
> .....
> 100³ = 35³ + 70³ + 85³
> ```

I've tried this:

```php
$start = microtime(true);
funcC(100);
echo microtime(true) - $start;    

function funcC($n){

    $tnum = 3;
    $s = '³';

    $testmax = $n-$tnum;
    $p3a = array();

    $numlist = array_fill(0, 10, array());


    for ($i = 0; $i <= $n; $i++) {
        $j = pow($i,3);
        $p3a[] = $j;
        $numlist[$j%10][$j] = $i;
    }




    for ($i = $tnum; $i <= $n; $i++) {
        $ipow = $p3a[$i];
        for ($j = 1; $j <= $i; $j++) {

            for ($k = $j+1; $k <= $testmax+2; $k++) {

                if($p3a[$j]+$p3a[$k] > $ipow){break;}

                $diff = $ipow - ($p3a[$j]+$p3a[$k]);
                $diff_t =  $diff%10;


                if(isset($numlist[$diff_t][$diff]) && $numlist[$diff_t][$diff]>$k ){

                    echo " $i$s  =  $j$s + $k$s + ".$numlist[$diff_t][$diff].$s.'<br>'.PHP_EOL;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It is ok, but I want to know a faster way of doing this.

This code uses 0.59064292907715 as test code [here](http://codepad.org/gWy9ptQ0).

Comment: Have you tried *not* using precalculated values?

Comment: @JOELEE pardon my ignorance, but what is the name of the mathematical formula/principle for finding out the numbers on the right hand side?

Answer (score 7):

I would make a few changes for readability:

- Rename:

  - `$p3a` → `$cubes`
  - `$numlist` → `$cubeRoots`
- Hard-code `$tnum`.  It's not going to vary anyway, since it wasn't a parameter.
- Eliminate `$testmax`.  It's not worth the effort to save a few loop iterations.
- More generous horizontal spacing.  (You use lots of newlines in your source code, but need more spaces.)

Changing `$numlist` from a two-level array to a 1-dimensional array results in better readability as well as a performance improvement.

`$i * $i * $i` is simpler and faster than `pow($i, 3)`.

Changing the termination condition of your inner loop results in an even more dramatic performance improvement.

Overall, this completes in about 1/3 of the time of the original code:

```
function funcC($n) {
    $exp = '³';

    $cubes = array();
    $cubeRoots = array();

    for ($i = 0; $i <= $n; $i++) {
        $j = $i * $i * $i;
        $cubes[$i] = $j;
        $cubeRoots[$j] = $i;
    }

    for ($i = 3; $i <= $n; $i++) {

        for ($j = 1; $j <= $i; $j++) {
            for ($k = $j; ($diff = $cubes[$i] - $cubes[$j] - $cubes[$k]) >= $cubes[$k]; $k++) {
                if (isset($cubeRoots[$diff])) {
                    echo " $i$exp  =  $j$exp + $k$exp + " . $cubeRoots[$diff] . $exp . '<br>' . PHP_EOL;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: http://codepad.org/FXTw5ENn   this code just return 15 line..

Comment: Silly mistake — reversed an inequality. Fixed in [Rev 2](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/revisions/41185/2).

Answer (score 3):

- [My old code](http://codepad.org/gWy9ptQ0):

  0.59064292907715 seconds
  loop count = 100 + (100*100*100)
- [200_success' code](http://codepad.org/asX8Wakc):

  0.13945198059082 seconds
  loop count =  100 + (100*100*100)
- I find the new way [here](http://codepad.org/Hvr5pKLh):

  0.090393781661987 seconds
  loop count = 100*100 + 100*100

  then

  ```
  $cubeRoots[$a][$i] = $i.$exp.'+'.$k.$exp;  => $cubeRoots[$a][$i] = $k;
  ```

  0.085232019424438 seconds

```
<?php
$start = microtime(true);
funcC(100);
echo microtime(true) - $start; 
function funcC($n) {
    $exp = '³';

    $cubes = array();
    $cubeRoots = array();

    for ($i = 2; $i <= $n; $i++) {
        $j = $i * $i * $i;
        $cubes[$i] = $j;

        for ($k = $i+1; $k <= $n; $k++) {
            $a=$j+($k*$k*$k);
            if(!isset($cubeRoots[$a])){
               $cubeRoots[$a] = array(); 
            }
        //$cubeRoots[$a][$i] = $i.$exp.'+'.$k.$exp;
                      $cubeRoots[$a][$i] = $k;
        }

    }

    for ($i = 3; $i <= $n; $i++) {

        for ($j = 1; $j <= $i; $j++) {

            $diff = $cubes[$i] - $cubes[$j];
            if (isset($cubeRoots[$diff])) {
                foreach($cubeRoots[$diff] AS $key => $v){
                    if($j< $key){
                    //echo " $i$exp  =  $j$exp  + " . $v  . '<br>' . PHP_EOL;

echo " $i$exp  =  $j$exp  + $key$exp+ $v$exp <br>" . PHP_EOL;
                    }
                }

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: `$cubeRoots` is no longer an accurate name. Try changing `$cubeRoots[$a][$i] = $i.$exp.'+'.$k.$exp` to `$cubePartitions[$a][$i] = $k`.

Comment: You are right .. 0.085232019424438  very good..